# Characteristic polynomial of square of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $p_A(x)=(-1)^n\cdot (x-λ_1)\dots(x-λ_n)$ it's characteristic polynomial.

Prove that $p_{A^2}(x)=(-1)^n\cdot (x-λ_1^2)\dots(x-λ_n^2)$

Any tips on where to start from?

Comment: Hint: $A^2-x^2I=(A-xI)(A+xI)$, hence $\det{(A^2-x^2I)}=\det{(A-xI)}\det{(A+xI)}$.

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic polynomial of a matrix has roots that are equal to its eigenvalues. Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Then
$$
AAx = A \lambda x = \lambda^2 x.
$$
So $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ too, but its eigenvalue is $\lambda^2$.  So the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $AA$ are the squares of the roots of $A$.  Its characteristic polynomial is completely determined by this fact.